# Get facebook friends upon registration

Tags: python, django, facebook-authentication

When a user registers for my site through Facebook. It returns "3 friends have registered" next to the 'Register' button with the Facebook authentication API.

```
def facebook_authenticated(request):
    try:
        code = request.GET['code']
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/?error=facebook')

    redirect_url = "yaddayadaa"

    args = dict(client_id=settings.FACEBOOK_API_ID, redirect_uri=redirect_url)
    args["client_secret"] = settings.FACEBOOK_API_SECRET
    args["code"] = code

    response = cgi.parse_qs(urllib.urlopen(
        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" +
        urllib.urlencode(args)).read())
    access_token = response["access_token"][-1]

    graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="+access_token

    profile = json.load(urllib.urlopen(graph_url))

    member_id = str(profile['id'])

    try:
        new_user = FacebookProfile.objects.get(facebook_id=member_id).user
        fbprofile = FacebookProfile.objects.get(user=new_user)
        if access_token != fbprofile.access_token:
            fbprofile.access_token = access_token
            fbprofile.save()
    except (User.DoesNotExist, ObjectDoesNotExist):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/?error=facebook')
```

How would I get the 3 users and store, such that the registering user can connect with them on my site?

I haven't found any examples of how to accomplish this, or what parts of the API are useful to do this.

Comment: Based on the conversation in DNCS's answer below, this really sounds like a "plz send me teh codez".  People on Stack don't like people who cry out with "plz send me teh codez".  So I think you've gotten all the help you're going to get.  I'd be suprised if anyone helps you any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once that user accepts permissions to your app, you can call the `/me/friends` to get a list of friends, then you can parse thru that list looking at the `installed` property to determine if that friend is one of your app users.

Another way, the better of the two as only one call as well as no parsing after the call, would be to use FQL to query the friends list

`fql?q=SELECT uid, name, is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) and is_app_user=1`

**EDIT**

PHP example of how to run FQL code. Taken from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

```
<?php
  $app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
  $app_secret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
  $my_url = 'POST_AUTH_URL';

  $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

 //auth user
 if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' 
    . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) ;
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
  }

  //get user access_token
  $token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
    . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) 
    . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret 
    . '&code=' . $code;
  $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  // Run fql query
  $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . '/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()'
    . '&' . $access_token;
  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
  $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);

  //display results of fql query
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r("query results:");
  print_r($fql_query_obj);
  echo '</pre>';

  // Run fql multiquery
  $fql_multiquery_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . 'fql?q={"all+friends":"SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()",'
    . '"my+name":"SELECT+name+FROM+user+WHERE+uid=me()"}'
    . '&' . $access_token;
  $fql_multiquery_result = file_get_contents($fql_multiquery_url);
  $fql_multiquery_obj = json_decode($fql_multiquery_result, true);

  //display results of fql multiquery
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r("multi query results:");
  print_r($fql_multiquery_obj);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. To be completely honest, I need to see an example on how to implement that. (I'm just learning) and I really don't know how or where to use fql.

Comment: I did give an example of using the FQL I wrote the **complete statement** for you. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ for examples of how to call this FQL statement. Also http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ for more info on FQL. A lot of great example codes for doing it there.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that I'm not implementing php. Trying to find cases using Django/Python. Seems so easy with php, but alas; I'm stuck with what I'm using.

Comment: Pretend that the PHP code is pseudo code and based upon this pseudo code write it with Python.

Comment: Do you hope to get the complete working python codez?  Or just a sample to help you get started?

Comment: @CoderFromOuterSpace, Ideally both. But I learn better from sample code and figuring out how to make it work with my app.

Comment: This really sounds like a "plz send me teh codez".  People on Stack don't like people who cry out with "plz send me teh codez".  So I think you've gotten all the help you're going to get.

Comment: @CoderFromOuterSpace, Guess you missed where I said "I learn better from sample code and figuring out how to make it work with my app".

Comment: You got yourself some pseudo code, and links to documentation.  What more do you really need?

Comment: @CoderFromOuterSpace, thanks for the backup.  But I think I can handle this.  Could you please excuse yourself from this conversation please?

Comment: @DMCS, I looked into `/me/friends` more thoroughly, and that seems to be what I'm looking for. Thank you again for your help and patience!